# To which country did MiGs in Top Gun belong?

Tags: plot-explanation, top-gun

In [*Top Gun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gun), a US warship is placed in the Indian Ocean. 
In the opening and climax of the movie, US fighter planes are in a dogfight with MiGs, but the country is not revealed.

Why was a US warship present in the Indian Ocean, and to which country did these MiGs belong?

Comment: usually MiGs are from Russia and/or allies from Russia

Comment: @Vishwa there was no Russia in 1986, only the Soviet Union

Comment: @TK-421: no need to be pedantic. Russia has been existing as a nation way before USSR.

Comment: @Taladris And Babylonia existed as a country way before Iraq, but if you tried to answer a question with Babylonia when you mean Iraq, it would cause more confusion than enlightenment. That said, TK-421 is wrong. Russia _did_ exist in 1986, as the largest of the sovereign Republics that made up the USSR. Saying it didn't exist would be like saying that Texas doesn't currently exist because it's now a state that's part of the US and no longer an independent nation.

Comment: @TK-421 As others have mentioned, Russia absolutely existed in 1986. In addition, as it was the largest and most powerful SSR in the Union, and the government of the USSR was seated in the capital of Russia, the terms “Russia” and “The USSR” were used interchangeably during the 80s, and probably for most of the existence of the USSR. Even presidents and chairmen of the joint chiefs and Secretaries of State and defense would refer to the USSR as “Russia” in speeches.

Comment: @ToddWilcox "Russia" as a country refers to modern Russia since 1991. Previously it was "Russian Soviet Republic" as a part of the USSR (1917-1991), and even before that it was The Russian Empire (1721-1917) and before it was Tsardom of Russia (1547–1721) and before it was Grand Duchy of Moscow (1283–1547) and earlier it was Ruś (882–1240), so Russia as "Russia" did not exist before 1991. Elezar - It is more like saying that the State of Texas existed before 1845. It didn't. The Republic of Texas did and earlier it lived as part of Mexico.

Comment: @TK-421 The Russian SFSR was one of the fifteen constituent of the Soviet Union, so it did definitely exist. But I agree that it would be better to refer to the MiGs as "Soviet", not "Russian". ""Russia" as a country refers to modern Russia since 1991.". No, it doesn't. it depends on the period you are talking about and the context.

Comment: Well I'm certainly glad we cleared that up

Comment: "The terms “Russia” and “The USSR” were used interchangeably during the 80s" - I don't know about the rest of the world, but not in the USSR itself. Also: half of the population was not Russian, the leaders were often not Russian as well. Taking the longest-ruling ones, Stalin was Georgian and Brezhnev was Ukrainian.  So the USSR and Russia (RSFSR) are not the same.

Comment: @Malcolm They were used interchangeably in the US where *Top Gun* was set and filmed. I don’t think anyone is asserting that Russia and the Soviet Union have ever actually been the same thing. Merely that in the 80s, Americans quite often said “Russia” when they meant “The Soviet Union” or “USSR”. A survey of other 80s movies is one way to see this in action. Characters frequently refer to “the Russians” or a “Russian invasion” or “Russian missiles” when they are really talking about either the USSR or sometimes the entire Warsaw Pact.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I know, I left the comment just in case someone has any misconceptions about how the Soviet Union actually worked.

Comment: @Malcolm Oh I see. When you wrote “I don’t know about the rest of the world”, I thought that meant you didn’t know.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I meant in the sense that I can't speak for the rest of the world.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The country of origin for the MiG 28s (see footnote) was left intentionally vague. It would have been easy to have the pilots converse in their native language or even adorn the aircraft with unequivocal identification schemes.

> That the enemy was never officially established in Proser's early draft or Jack Epps Jr's final script. This was likely intentional: villainous governments in the movies are routinely left vague as to not piss off their real-world counterparts, with the exception of North Korea, possibly because North Korea doesn't have a strong market for movies or video games.
>   <sub>source: [Task & Purpose - Brad Howard](https://taskandpurpose.com/top-gun-bad-guy)</sub>

[image]

Regarding their identification markings:

> However, the markings on the fictional MiG-28 aren't Soviet. The MiG-28 in the film has a single red star surrounded by a yellow circle on their tail as their only marking, while Soviet aircraft traditionally had a white trim to their red star (just to cover my bases, the North Korean Air Force uses a blue trim). However, one country does, in fact, use yellow trim on their red star insignia: China.
>   <sub>source: [Task & Purpose - Brad Howard](https://taskandpurpose.com/top-gun-bad-guy)</sub>

[image]

At least one of the script's draft identified the aggressors as North Korean.

> Despite the markings, North Korea is still a good guess. Producers Jerry Bruckheimer and Don Simpson had more than one writer working on the Top Gun script. Along with Proser's draft, Jim Cash and Jack Epps, Jr. were hired to write another draft of the screenplay for the film that initially identified North Korea as the threat that Maverick and Co take on in the thrilling finale.
>   <sub>source: [Task & Purpose - Brad Howard](https://taskandpurpose.com/top-gun-bad-guy)</sub>

During script rewrites, the conflict was moved to the Indian Ocean which further confuses the issue. Which nation sporting MiG28s supposedly armed with French made AM 39 Exocet anti-ship missile(s) would be so protective of that area?

So there is no definitive country of origin.

---

<sub>Apparently, the fictional MiG-28 aggressor aircraft used in the Top Gun film were actually a mix of Northrop single-seat F-5E Tiger II and two-seat F-5F Tiger II aircraft.</sub>

Comment: India was the main (only?) nation in the area that used Soviet kit and was wealthy enough to buy enough planes and care about the IO that much.  But they weren't antagonistic towards the US.

Comment: One other thing interesting about the aircraft used in *Too Gun* is that A-4 Skyhawks were portrayed as the mock aggressors used at Miramar NAS during training, which is true to life, but another type of craft was also used as aggressors at Miramar: the F-5.

Comment: Isn't there also a scene where the enemy pilot mumbles something and mimics Arabic?

Comment: "*Unknown forces" - https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/TopGun.html; "Unknown forces" - https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/top-gun-1986.pdf

Answer (score 5):

> Audio commentary on the film's Special-Edition DVD release states that
>   they were originally intended to be North Korean.

This [source](https://topgun.fandom.com/wiki/MiG-28) states that they were meant to be North Korean, but no information was actually included in the movie.

The movie takes place in [1986](http://www.themovietimeline.com/film1312), while Russia was not an independent state yet, only the Soviet Union and other communistic states. Also, the MiG-28 is not a real plane, but an American Northrop F-5 painted black.

There is also no way to determine which countries used such planes in real life. However, a similar plane - MiG-29, which has been in production during 1986, was or still is, operated by [about 30 countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mikoyan_MiG-29_operators).